# Measurable graph implies measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $(X,S)$ is a measurable space and $f$ is a function from $X$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $\text{graph}(f)=\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}$ is a measurable set w.r.t product sigma-algebra $S\times B$, where $B$ is the sigma-algebra of Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$.
Prove that $f$ is a measurable function.

This is a converse to a well-known exercise that shows a measurable function has measurable graph, but I think this converse is probably harder. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't think this is true. Where did you find it?

Comment: this is an exercise from Axler's measure theory textbook.

Comment: @supinf I checked that the cross section of graph(f) at each real value b is an S-measurable subset of X, which implies that (f^-1)(b) is measurable for each real b. But then I am stuck at showing the inverse of all Borel measurable set is S-measurable.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti could you give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: @Biden I had misread your question as being about the converse, I don't know if this direction is true in this generality. For example even proving that a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ which has a Borel graph in $\Bbb R^2$ is a Borel function is not trivial, and it is usually done via Suslin's separation theorem saying that a set in a Polish space $X$ is Borel iff it is $\mathbf{\Delta}^1_1(X)$